# How to set the ninject binding for my MVC Controller if my Ninject reference is not on my web project?

Tags: c#, ninject

Disclaimer: This question started as a technical question but over the time changed to a question that has no right or wrong answer. I'm sorry for that. However, I would ask you politely to keep it open so we can improve this solution together.

I am starting with Ninject on an MVC4 project.
I setup my solution in projects like this:

- Web
- Business
- Data
- Model
- Infrastructure (Where the ninject reference should go)

My problem is now that I can't resolve my controller, I have the following

Binding:

```
public class Module : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        //Bind<IHttpControllerActivator>().To<MyHttpControllerActivator>();
        Bind<ISomething>().To<ConcreteSomething>();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ISomething smt;
    public HomeController(ISomething smt)
    {
        this.smt = smt;
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Bootstrap.Init();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

BootstrapClass:

```
 public class Bootstrap
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

It looks fine for me and pretty decoupled. My problem is now that I can't use the controller, I get the message:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

I read that I would have to change my MvcApplication to inherit from NinjectHttpApplication instead of HttpApplication, but I can't because I am not referencing Ninject from this project.
Is there anyway I can set the binding for my controller?

Thanks!

Edit 1:
In order to make this possible, I did this:

I had to add this class

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;
    public NinjectControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        ninjectKernel = kernel;
    }


    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        try
        {
            Type controllerType = base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);
            return ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType) as IController;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }
    }
}
```

And changed my bootstrap class:

```
public class Bootstrap
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory(kernel));

    }
}
```

Edit 2:
As a questions raised when commenting @Simon's answer:
Please correct me if I am wrong, but if I make the project architecture as you propose:

```
UI ------------> Bootstrapper -----
 |                    |           |
 |                    |           |
 ˅                    |           |
Business <-------------           |
 |                    |           |
 |                    |           |
 ˅                    ˅           |
Data --------------> Model        |
  ^                               |
  |_______________________________|
```

I would have the system tied together anyway, that would beat the reason of using IoC.

This would be my ideal architecture:

```
UI <------------ Bootstrapper -----
                      |           |
                      |           |
                      |           |
Business <-------------           |
                      |           |
                      |           |
                      ˅           |
Data --------------> Model        |
  ^                               |
  |_______________________________|
```

This brings me an issues that is: where can I store my interfaces, so they are accessible by everyone without any reference requirement.
A second issue would be: how can I initialize the bootstrap project, if the "main method" is in my UI project?
This brings me to my proposal, please let me know your thoughts and pros&cons

```
      --------------------------------------------
     |                                           |
     |                                           v
    UI ------------> Bootstrapper ----------> Interfaces
                          |           |           ^
                          |           |           |
                          |           |           |
  --Business <-------------           |           |
  |                       |           |           |
  |                       |           |           |
  |                       ˅           |           |
  |--Data --------------> Model       |           |
  |    ^                              |           |
  |    |______________________________|           |
  |_______________________________________________|
```

This way I would decouple the interfaces and make the three main layers completely decoupled one from another.
There would be a problem that business interfaces would be mixed with data interfaces, this is true. This problem can be minimized by organizing the project and by disciplined used by the programmer (would be enough for a small project as mine). For a bigger project, maybe breaking that in different projects would solve the problem (but bring a new one by creating a high number of projects inside the solution).

I had to change the orientation of the reference between the UI and the bootstrap project, so I can initialize that.

Please could you give me your thoughts about it? What are the pros&cons you see here?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this class

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;
    public NinjectControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        ninjectKernel = kernel;
    }


    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        try
        {
            Type controllerType = base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);
            return ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType) as IController;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }
    }
}
```

And changed my bootstrap class:

```
public class Bootstrap
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory(kernel));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.

Generally, your UI *must* know about what it is using to be bootstrapped. This doesn't mean you need to bootstrap everything in your UI... but your UI project needs to know whats happening (this is all assuming I understand your question properly).

Therefore, you can do this:

1) Reference Ninject in your UI project. This is a must. It needs to be able to resolve `NinjectHttpApplication`.

2) Have this sort of setup in your Global.asax.cs:

```
private readonly IKernel _kernel;

public IKernel CreateKernel() { // Ninject calls this after inheriting
                                // from NinjectHttpApplication
    _kernel = Bootstrap.Init();

    return _kernel;
}
```

3) Change `Bootstrap.Init` to return an `IKernel`:

```
public class Bootstrap {
    public IKernel Init() {
        return new StandardKernel(new NinjectModule[] {
            new YourModule(),
            new YourOtherModule()
        });
    }
}
```

4) This makes your flow of dependency somewhat like this:

```
-- Ninject References in both UI and Bootstrapper --

UI ------------> Bootstrapper -----
 |                    |           |
 |                    |           |
 ˅                    |           |
Business <-------------           |
 |                    |           |
 |                    |           |
 ˅                    ˅           |
Data --------------> Model        |
  ^                               |
  |_______________________________|
```

So your UI references the Bootstrapper and the Business projects. The Bootstrapper references everything so that you can setup your bindings nicely. Basically, the Bootstrapper is an umbrella.. it knows about everything so that it can bind everything. You'll notice though, that the rest of the projects point down. What you are proposing in your question would result in a circular reference.

Also, depending on where you map Domain objects to ViewModels, your UI may also need to reference the Model project. Which is fine.

Comment: And what do you think about my answer? This would make my UI independent of nInject.
I do not get the idea of the UI referencing the Business and the business referencing the Data. What would be the advantage of using IoC here? They would be tied up together. I will update my question with my architecture proposal.

Comment: Your UI is still tied to Ninject in your answer. You're setting the controller factory .. which is only available in the UI. Also, the waterfall dependencies are exactly as they should be. I'm not sure how you have your Data layer setup, but generally the data access logic such as Repositories or a CQRS setup resides in that layer. The Business layer needs to be able to call into it to persist.

Comment: The controller factory would be set in my bootstraper/infrastructure project, so the UI would not be tied to nInject. Yes, the data access logic would be setup in that layer, but I would like to be able to change this logic without impacts on the business. 
I updated my question, what do you think about my proposal?

Comment: I don't understand what stops you from switching out any functionality in what I have described. Each layer should only depend on abstractions from the next layer down.. which means actual implementations can be switched out as much as you want.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to back back to you. True, please correct if I am wrong, but as far as I know, If my business layer references the data and uses an interface w/ the fullname Data.Interfaces.DataAcess this interface will have to be in this new DLL (and I don't know if this would work without recompiling the business). If the data has a reference to the business, to change the data you just have to create a new project and use the interfaces present on the business layer. The BL would not require any change/recompilation.

Comment: You could argue that changing the business layer would be harder. That is true, but in my opinion, the BL is the "heart" of a project. Replacing it would mean basically starting a new project.